# Untracked files persist in multiple branches

Tags: visual-studio-code

I usually use vscode switching between multiple git branches at the same time. I noticed that if I create a new file in one branch and checkout another branch, the new file persists. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, that's how git works.

Comment: Is there a way to like isolate branches from each other? Right now, I can only think of cloning the repo again and again, but the repo has a size of 200mb!

Comment: No, a branch is just a pointer to a commit. You need to stash or commit your changes if you don't want them to stay in the working copy.